# Puppeteer, generate pdf from HTTP

Tags: api, docker, http, puppeteer

looking for experts help

I am running Grafana in docker, puppeteer in docker and I am able to generate pdf file by running following command from host

`sudo docker exec puppeteer node /grafana_pdf.js http://grafana:3000/d/qP-sbQEZz/new-dashboard?kiosk USER:PASSWORD /pdf-reports/qa_report.pdf`

I would like to have a possibility to have puppeteer in docker and not need to run manually node + link to generate pdf but use browser like google chrome to insert link and get pdf in browser. Like insert link below to URL and I get pdf in page

`http://grafana:3000/api/qP-sbQEZz/new-dashboard?kiosk`

Is there a way to have puppeteer listen to requests such as above and generate the report rather then manually running `node grafana_pdf.js`? If so, what changes and where I have to make ?

Here is js file I use to generate pdf from link as argument
[grafana_pdf.js](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/svet-b/1ad0656cd3ce0e1a633e16eb20f66425/raw/29ea176e055710bfc50834f4816377a26e890927/grafana_pdf.js)

Thank you